# What libraries are needed for this binary to run?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, binaryfiles

Linux-based (Ubuntu 11.10)

Before my computer crashed I had a binary on my computer: `./program` that was given to me without the source. This file executed just fine. When my hard drive failed, I started with a fresh install and tried to run this binary on the same computer. It now fails with:

```
bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file
```

Running `ldd` on the file gives a bit more information:

```
/usr/bin/ldd: line 161: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: cannot execute binary file
not a dynamic executable
```

I have a second computer where the binary runs and `ldd` gives the output:

```
./program:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdad5e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00000039a1400000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/gcc/gcc-4.5.1/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fce82c7a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fce829f6000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/gcc/gcc-4.5.1/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fce827e1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fce82452000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fce82f7f000)
```

Is there a way I can tell what is needed so I can get my program running again? I know that anything installed before the crash was done with `apt-get` so I don't think it requires anything unique that's not in the repository.

**Localized question?**

I admit that this *specific* question may be particular to me - but the question still stands in the general sense. Given a binary only, how do you determine which libraries it needs to run?

Comment: try `nm -u program` to see what unresolved symbols are there?

Comment: @Kimvais on each computer there are a ton of entries, but in both cases a  `diff` shows they are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `file` with the program as argument on the computer where `ldd` works. It will tell you if the binary is built for 32 or 64 bits. You probably have to install the 32 bit compatibility libraries before it will run, on debian/ubuntu this is called `ia32-libs`.

Comment: `file` gives `program: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped` so it looks to be built for my 64-bit machine (both machines are 64 bit).

Comment: OK. Do you have a file named /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ? Do you have one with another version at the end? Try creating a symlink pointing to /lib64/ld-x.y.so

Comment: This may be the problem then, while I do have `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, I don't have any file `ld-x.y.so`, nor will Google tell me what this belongs to.

Comment: /lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so and /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 comes from the `libc6` deb package on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: Found this tidbit buried inside a PDF:

To install 32-bit runtime support, Execute the following commands: 

 - $ `sudo apt-get update`
 - $ `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Note that this installs over 200 packages, and takes several minutes to complete.

Doing this allowed me to run under 64-bit Linux:`ldd` on, for instance, the NVIDIA `nvflash` binary for which source is not public.